# Knex cannot find table in Cloud SQL Postgres from Cloud Functions

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, knex.js

I am trying to connect to a Postgres 12 DB running in Cloud SQL from a Cloud Function written in TypeScript.

I create the database with the following:

```
import * as Knex from "knex"

const { username, password, instance } = ... // username, password, connection name (<app-name>:<region>:<database>)

const config = {
   client: 'pg',
   connection: {
      user: username,
      password: password, 
      database: 'ingredients',
      host: `/cloudsql/${instance}`,
      pool: { min: 1, max: 1}
   }
}

const knex = Knex(config as Knex.Config)
```

I am then querying the database using:

```
const query = ... // passed in as param
const result = await knex('tableName').where('name', 'ilike', query).select('*')
```

When I run this code, I get the following error in the Cloud Functions logs:

```
Unhandled error { error: select * from "tableName" where "name" ilike $1 - relation "tableName" does not exist
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.stream.on (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:10:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

I created the table using the following commands in the GCP Cloud Shell (then populated with a data from a CSV):

```
\connect ingredients;
CREATE TABLE tableName (name VARCHAR(255), otherField VARCHAR(255), ... );
```

In that console, if I run the query `SELECT * FROM tableName;`, I see the correct data listed.

Why does Knex not see the table: `tableName`, but the GCP Cloud Shell does?

BTW, I am definitely connecting to the correct db, as I see the same error logs in the Cloud SQL logging interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are creating the table `tableName` without quoting, which makes it actually lower case (case insensitive). So when creating schema do:

```
CREATE TABLE "tableName" ("name" VARCHAR(255), "otherField" VARCHAR(255), ... );
```

or use only lower-case table / column names.